# Cordova plugin media capture error 20

Tags: cordova

I'm using the cordova media capture package
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture

When trying to use:

```
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:1});
```

I am getting a error:20 on my IOS simulator. I cant really find anything only.
Cordova version 3.4
IOS version 8

Anyone seen this error before?

Cheers
Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error code 20 refers to the media i/p not available. Ex. if you are trying to capture a video on an iOS simulator.