# Capture video and store it on the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, cordova-plugins

I try to capture a video with Apache Cordova Plugin [cordova-plugin-media-capture](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media-capture/index.html). How can i send this video to my server and store it?

This is an official example on how to start capturing a video:

```
// capture callback
var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
    var i, path, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
        // do something interesting with the file
    }
};

// capture error callback
var captureError = function(error) {
    navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
};

// start video capture
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:2, duration: 10});
```

But how can i send the video to my server to store it?
What do i have to pass to my ajax code?

```
// capture callback
var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) 
{
    var i, path, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) 
    {
        path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
        $.ajax
        (
            "ajax.php", 
            {
                type: "POST",
                data: { path: path }   //This will just send the path to the server
            }
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: send the file to the server. might need to read the file first...

Comment: It is exactly my question how to do this...

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

**Better to use this Function.**

```
function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
    var ft = new FileTransfer(),
        path = mediaFile.fullPath,
        name = mediaFile.name;
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.mimeType = "video/mpeg";
    options.fileName = name;
    options.chunkedMode = true;

    ft.upload(path,
        "**Your WebService Url Goes Here**",
        function(result) {
            console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
            console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
        },
        options);
}
```

`Call this function where you are getting your File Path`.

**Like Below.**

```
uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
```

**EDIT 1**

**Note:** `Make sure you added all below plugins in your project.`

```
cordova-plugin-media

cordova-plugin-media-capture 

cordova-plugin-file

cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly i can't test it because i always get `Cannot read property 'capture' of undefined`

Comment: Then may be the problem in the installation of plugins.

Comment: I installed the plugins `cordova-plugin-camera` and `cordova-plugin-file`

Comment: @EdwardBlack Check my edited answer. i have added list of plugins you need to install.

Comment: @EDIT 1: Now i get `Error in Error callbackId: Capture695894522 : TypeError: Cannot read property 'alert' of undefined` and `cordova.js:985 Exception calling native with command :: Capture :: captureVideo ::exception=TypeError: Cannot read property 'alert' of undefined`

Comment: @EdwardBlack Not used of `Alert` Anywhere in above code. From where you getting this error ? I have used `Console.log` else.

Comment: I think it is from `navigator.notification.alert` do i miss another plugin for notification?

Comment: @EdwardBlack Yes if you have used `navigator.notification.alert` then you need to install notification plugins also. Install it the error will go away.

Comment: Indeed, i added `cordova-plugin-dialogs` now there are no error messages anymore. But now i get `Error code 20` if i try to make a picture ... im sorry but i can't test your code, i don't know why it is not working.

Comment: @EdwardBlack Can you show full `Error` for `Error code 20`. Are you getting it when executing file upload code ?

Comment: It only pops up an alert with `Error code 20`. I will investigate it tomorrow. I found this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973909/cordova-plugin-media-capture-error-20

Comment: @EdwardBlack Okay sure :).

Comment: not yet, i can only try it tomorrow, i will let you know :)

Comment: @EdwardBlack Okay sure :). Let me know if it solved or if you face any problem. Thanks :).